# java - client - server multiple messages from client

Tags: java, server, client, communication

I'm learning about server - client communication, I have made a simple communicator, it works, but I can only send one message to the server. I don't know how to make a possibility to send and receive more messages from client. I have tried a lot of options, but none work.

Here is my code: 
Client:
        import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;

```
    public class Klient
    {
       public static final int PORT=50007;
       public static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException                            
   {                                                                                   

      Socket sock;                                                                     
      sock=new Socket(HOST,PORT);                                                      
      System.out.println("communication works: "+sock);                              


      BufferedReader klaw;                                                             
      klaw=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                       
      PrintWriter outp;                                                                
      outp=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());                                    


      System.out.print("<Sending:> ");                                                
      String str=klaw.readLine();                                                      
      outp.println(str);                                                               
      outp.flush();                                                                    


      klaw.close();                                                                    
      outp.close();                                                                    
      sock.close();                                                                    
   }                                                                                   
}
```

and Server:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Serwer
{
   public static final int PORT=50007;

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException                  
   {                                                                         

      ServerSocket serv;                                                     
      serv=new ServerSocket(PORT);                                           


      System.out.println("listen for: "+serv);                               
      Socket sock;                                                           
      sock=serv.accept();                                                    
      System.out.println("communication: "+sock);                          


      BufferedReader inp;                                                    
      inp=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream())); 

      String str;                                                            
      str=inp.readLine();                                                    
      System.out.println("<it comes:> " + str);                              


      inp.close();                                                           
      sock.close();                                                          
      serv.close();                                                          
   }                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a main loop for your code and special command for quit

in example:

```
// infinite loop
while (true) {

   // ..receive or send commands here..

   if (command.equals("exit") {
     // exit from loop
   }

}
```

Also add exception handling (try-catch-finally) or you app will be very fragile

Answer (score 1):

A TCP socket sends data in a stream. TCP does not support sending data in "messages" or "blocks". What you're doing in the code is sending and receiving a stream.

To send "messages" using TCP, an application protocol must be defined on top of TCP. This protocol should have the ability to send "messages". (if you don't understand this part you should read about protocol layers, 7 layers OSI model, and 5 layers TCP/IP suite)

A way to do this is to define a message-termination character. The stream would look like this:

```
<message><termination-character><message><termination-character>
```

The termination character is either a character from the message charset or outside of it. In the latter case, any occurrence of the termination character in the message should be replaced by an escape sequence.

Suppose we use '\n' as a termination character and we assume that '\n' is not in the message charset. Your client should look like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

    public class Klient
    {
    public static final int PORT=50007;
    public static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    public static final char TERMINATIONCHAR = '\n';

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException                            
    {                                                                                   

        Socket sock;                                                                     
        sock=new Socket(HOST,PORT);                                                      
        System.out.println("communication works: "+sock);                              


        BufferedReader klaw;                                                             
        klaw=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                       
        PrintWriter outp;                                                                
        outp=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());                                    

        //define the loop
        while(true){
            System.out.print("<Sending:> ");                                                
            String str=klaw.readLine(); 
            outp.print(str+TERMINATIONCHAR);                                                               
            outp.flush();
        }

        /* uncomment if the loop can be exited
        klaw.close();                                                                    
        outp.close();                                                                    
        sock.close();*/
    }                                                                                   
}
```

and your Server should look like this:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server
{
    public static final int PORT=50007;
    public static final char TERMINATIONCHAR = '\n';

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException                  
    {                                                                         

        ServerSocket serv;                                                     
        serv=new ServerSocket(PORT);                                           


        System.out.println("listen for: "+serv);                               
        Socket sock;                                                           
        sock=serv.accept();                                                    
        System.out.println("communication: "+sock);                          


        BufferedReader inp;                                                    
        inp=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream())); 

        //define the loop
        while(true){
            String str;                                                            
            str=inp.readLine();                                               
            System.out.println("<it comes:> " + str); 
        }

        /* uncomment if the loop can be exited
        inp.close();                                                           
        sock.close();                                                          
        serv.close();*/                                                                  
    }                                                                         
}
```